# VLC: Play on Fullscreen

Tags: macos, mac, vlc-media-player, playback

(Mac OS 10.6.8 Snow Leopard)

Is there any way, to configure VLC to start playing paused videos when it enters fullscreen mode like in older versions of QuickTime (or newer versions with this installed: https://github.com/sjaek/QTXAutoPlayFullscreen) ?

Comment: i don't know about the repository that you added via the given link in your question, but basically "space-bar" pauses and plays videos in vlc no matter if in window'ed or fullscreen-mod. you also can re-assign the keyboard-shortcut(s) for play/pause from within vlc player. to do so go to > Preferences `⌘,` > Hotkeys